# Where am I going wrong when analyzing this data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Trying to find a trend in attendance. I filtered my existing df to this so I can look at 1 activity at a time.

```
+---+-----------+-------+----------+-------+---------+
|   |   Date    |  Org  | Activity | Hours | Weekday |
+---+-----------+-------+----------+-------+---------+
| 0 | 8/3/2020  | Org 1 | Gen Ab   | 10.5  | Monday  |
| 1 | 8/25/2020 | Org 1 | Gen Ab   | 2     | Tuesday |
| 3 | 8/31/2020 | Org 1 | Gen Ab   | 8.5   | Monday  |
| 7 | 8/10/2020 | Org 2 | Gen Ab   | 1     | Monday  |
| 8 | 8/14/2020 | Org 3 | Gen Ab   | 3.5   | Friday  |
+---+-----------+-------+----------+-------+---------+
```

This code:

```
gen_ab = att_df.loc[att_df['Activity'] == "Gen Ab"]
sum_gen_ab = gen_ab.groupby(['Date', 'Activity']).sum()
sum_gen_ab.head()
```

Returns this:

```
+------------+----------+------------+
|            |          |   Hours    |
+------------+----------+------------+
| Date       | Activity |            |
| 06/01/2020 | Gen Ab   | 347.250000 |
| 06/02/2020 | Gen Ab   | 286.266667 |
| 06/03/2020 | Gen Ab   | 169.583333 |
| 06/04/2020 | Gen Ab   | 312.633333 |
| 06/05/2020 | Gen Ab   | 317.566667 |
+------------+----------+------------+
```

How do I make the summed column name 'Hours'? I still get the same result when I do this:

```
sum_gen_ab['Hours'] = gen_ab.groupby(['Date', 'Activity']).sum()
```

What I eventually want to do is have a line graph that shows the sum of hours for the activity over time. The time of course would be the dates in my df.

```
plt.plot(sum_gen_ab['Date'], sum_gen_ab['Hours'])
plt.show()
```

returns KeyError: Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've used `groupby(['Date', 'Activity'])` Date and Activity have been transformed to indices and can't be referenced with `sum_gen_ab['Date']`.

To avoid transforming them to indices you can use `groupby(['Date', 'Activity'], as_index=False)` instead.

Comment: Using `as_index=False` worked. Can you tell me what my original result was called? I mean where it had 'Hours' as the header or something.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your first result is grouped by date and activity, which by default transform the columns you group by to indices. I don't know if it has a specific name.

Answer (score 1):

I will typically use the pandasql library to manipulate my data frames into different datasets. This allows you to manipulate your pandas data frame with SQL code. Pandasql can be used alongside pandas.

EXAMPLE:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as psql

df = "will be your dataset"


new_dataset = psql.sqldf('''
SELECT DATE, ACTIVITY, SUM(HOURS) as SUM_OF_HOURS
FROM df
GROUP BY DATE, ACTIVITY''')

new_dataset.head() #Shows the first 5 rows of your dataset
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this library. I didn't use it for this solution but I can certainly use it in the future now